# LuaTeX node library: Vertical glue/kern does not work in manually made nodelist, what is missing?

Tags: luatex, lua

**This is a LuaTeX node-library/ node-list question.**

In the following code, I am trying to typeset a manually crafted nodelist. To add a line break, I add a penalty node, and that works fine (i.e. the line breaks at that point). But when I add a vertical glue/kern after the linebreak, it doesn't really add any vertical space. Where am I going wrong? What nodes are needed to tell the linebreak routine to add vertical space? Am expecting behavior similar to LaTeX's macros `\vspace{25pt}` or `\\[25pt]`.

> Sidenote lua questions: 1) Is the `require` way of loading the lua file ok? I mean, what if I have a `local` variable name clash with another lua file that I load with `require`, for instance variable `local head`? 2) Instead of making the functions global, is there a way to call them with something like `linebreak.` prefix to avoid name clash with other lua files that have functions with same name?
>
> Update: The "Sidenote" questions above are now discussed as a separate question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/571204/192717), please ignore above "Sidenote lua questions" while reading this question as they are not relevant to it.

Screenshot (I expect additional 25pt or 50pt vertical space after first line):
[image: Screenshot of output]

linebreak.tex:

```latex
>>> lualatex linebreak.tex
\documentclass{article}
\directlua{require"linebreak.lua"}
\begin{document}
\raggedright
\directlua{
    initialize()
    addchars('H')
    addchars('e')
    addchars('l')
    addchars('l')
    addchars('o')
    addchars(' ')
    addchars('W')
    addchars('o')
    addchars('r')
    addchars('l')
    addchars('d')
    addpenalty(1,-10000) % Add line break, works fine!
    addglue(1,25*65536) % XXX: Add vertical glue, doesn't work!
    addkern(1,25*65536) % XXX: Add vertical kern, doesn't work!
    addchars(' ')
    addchars('H')
    addchars('e')
    addchars('y')
    writeparagraph()
}
\end{document}
```

linebreak.lua:

```lua
local glyph_id = node.id("glyph")
local glue_id  = node.id("glue")
local kern_id  = node.id("kern")
local penalty_id = node.id("penalty")
local current_font = font.current()
local font_parameters = font.getfont(current_font).parameters
local n, head, last

function addchars(c)
  for s in string.utfvalues(c) do
    local char = unicode.utf8.char(s)
    if unicode.utf8.match(char,"%s") then
      -- its a space
      n = node.new(glue_id)
      n.width   = font_parameters.space
      n.shrink  = font_parameters.space_shrink
      n.stretch = font_parameters.space_stretch
    else -- a glyph
      n = node.new(glyph_id)
      n.font = current_font
      n.subtype = 1
      n.char = s
      n.lang = tex.language
      n.uchyph = 1
      n.left = tex.lefthyphenmin
      n.right = tex.righthyphenmin
    end
    last.next = n
    last = n
  end
  return last
end

function addpenalty(s,p)
    n = node.new(penalty_id)
    n.subtype = s or 0
    n.penalty = p or 0
    last.next = n
    last = n
    return n
end

function addkern(s,p)
    n = node.new(kern_id)
    n.subtype = s or 0
    n.kern = p or 0
    last.next = n
    last = n
    return n
end

function addglue(s,a,b,c,d,e)
    n = node.new(glue_id)
    n.subtype = s
    n.width = a or 0
    n.stretch = b or 0
    n.shrink = c or 0
    n.stretch_order = d or 0
    n.shrink_order = e or 0
    last.next = n
    last = n
    return n
end

function initialize()
    -- add parindent glue in the beginning, create head node
    head = node.new("glue")
    head.width = tex.parindent
    last = head
end

function writeparagraph()
    -- append a penalty and parfillskip glue at the end of list
    addpenalty(0,10000)
    addglue(15,0,tex.parfillskip.stretch,tex.parfillskip.stretch_order)
    -- create prev pointers
    node.slide(head)
    -- hyphenate
    lang.hyphenate(head)
    -- take care of fonts, kerning, ligature, etc
    head = nodes.simple_font_handler(head)
    -- call tex linebreaking, write to pdf
    tex.write(tex.linebreak(head))
    -- initize pointers
    head = nil
    last = nil
end
```

Comment: you can't add vertical glue in a horizontal list you need to put it in a vadjust node see the definition of `\vspace`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, it worked! I posted the modified code based on your recommendation as answer below. Do you have any inputs on my lua sidenote questions?

Comment: @reportaman I find it confusing to post a follow-up question as an answer. Could you post a new question or make it clear which part of the question have been resolved?

Comment: @reportaman Nice to see more people playing with node lists! Let's establish a "node list manipulator's club"

Comment: @reportaman the site format really doesn't support multiple questions in the same post: it's much better to ask new questions as new questions.  Basically you should structure your file as a module, that is do not define lots of global names just return a table containing all your functions, then the caller can choose the top level name `foo=require('yourfile') ...   foo.myfun() ...`

Comment: @topskip I posted a new question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/571204/192717. Yes!!! that sounds like a great idea ti gave a "node list manipulator's club", what's the best forum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [David Carlisle's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) comment to my question, I added an adjust node with vertical glue in it. Now the output is as desired. Here's the screenshot and code:

[image: Screenshot showing the output of modified code]

modified linebreak.tex:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\directlua{require"linebreak.lua"}
\begin{document}
\raggedright
\directlua{
    initialize()
    addchars('H')
    addchars('e')
    addchars('l')
    addchars('l')
    addchars('o')
    addchars(' ')
    addchars('W')
    addchars('o')
    addchars('r')
    addchars('l')
    addchars('d')
    addpenalty(1,-10000) % Add line break
    vspace(25*65536) % Add vspace
    addchars('H')
    addchars('e')
    addchars('y')
    writeparagraph()
}
\end{document}
```

modified linebreak.lua:

```lua
local glyph_id = node.id("glyph")
local glue_id  = node.id("glue")
local kern_id  = node.id("kern")
local penalty_id = node.id("penalty")
local adjust_id  = node.id("adjust")
local current_font = font.current()
local font_parameters = font.getfont(current_font).parameters
local n, head, last

function addchars(c)
  for s in string.utfvalues(c) do
    local char = unicode.utf8.char(s)
    if unicode.utf8.match(char,"%s") then
      -- its a space
      n = node.new(glue_id)
      n.width   = font_parameters.space
      n.shrink  = font_parameters.space_shrink
      n.stretch = font_parameters.space_stretch
    else -- a glyph
      n = node.new(glyph_id)
      n.font = current_font
      n.subtype = 1
      n.char = s
      n.lang = tex.language
      n.uchyph = 1
      n.left = tex.lefthyphenmin
      n.right = tex.righthyphenmin
    end
    last.next = n
    last = n
  end
  return last
end

function addpenalty(s,p)
    n = node.new(penalty_id)
    n.subtype = s or 0
    n.penalty = p or 0
    last.next = n
    last = n
    return n
end

function addkern(s,p)
    n = node.new(kern_id)
    n.subtype = s or 0
    n.kern = p or 0
    last.next = n
    last = n
    return n
end

function addadjust(s,h)
    n = node.new(adjust_id)
    n.subtype = s or 0
    n.head = h
    last.next = n
    last = n
    return n
end

function vspace(s)
    g1 = node.new(glue_id)
    g1.width = s
    g1.subtype = 0
    addadjust(1,g1)
end

function addglue(s,a,b,c,d,e)
    n = node.new(glue_id)
    n.subtype = s
    n.width = a or 0
    n.stretch = b or 0
    n.shrink = c or 0
    n.stretch_order = d or 0
    n.shrink_order = e or 0
    last.next = n
    last = n
    return n
end

function initialize()
    -- add parindent glue in the beginning, create head node
    head = node.new("glue")
    head.width = tex.parindent
    last = head
end

function writeparagraph()
    -- append a penalty and the parfillskip glue at the end of list
    addpenalty(0,10000)
    addglue(15,0,tex.parfillskip.stretch,tex.parfillskip.stretch_order)
    -- create prev pointers
    node.slide(head)
    -- hyphenate
    lang.hyphenate(head)
    -- take care of fonts, kerning, ligature, etc
    head = nodes.simple_font_handler(head)
    -- call linebreaking
    tex.write(tex.linebreak(head))
    -- initize pointers
    head = nil
    last = nil
end
```

Comment: the site format would be clearer if you removed the extra question (post as a new question) then self-accepted this answer to mark this question as done

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Done, here's the new question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/571204/192717