# LuaTeX: For adjust nodes, what is subtype normal, and pre?

Tags: luatex

What is the difference between subtype normal, and subtype pre of adjust nodes in LuaTeX? When to select one over another? In the answer to my question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/571180/192717), I chose subtype "pre", subtype normal also works (with order of `vspace()` and `addpenalty()` swapped).

Screenshot from documenation of luatex:

[image: Screenshot from documentation of luatex]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `normal` `adjust` node acts like `\vadjust{`<whatever you wrote in .head>`}`, while a `pre` `adjust` node will act like `\vadjust pre{`<whatever you wrote in .head>`}`. This leaves the question what `\vadjust pre` is doing. This is a pdfTeX feature, so we can look it up in the pdfTeX manual:

> `\vadjust [⟨pre spec⟩] ⟨filler⟩ {⟨vertical mode material⟩}` (h, m)
>
> The `\vadjust` implementation of pdfTEX adds an optional qualifier `⟨pre spec⟩`, which is simply the string `pre`, to the original TeX primitive with the same name. If no `pre` is given, `\vadjust` behaves exactly as the original (see the TeXbook, p. 281): it appends an adjustment item created from `⟨vertical mode material⟩` to the current list *after* the line in which `\vadjust` appears. However, with the qualifier `pre`,
> the adjustment item is put *before* the line in which `\vadjust pre` appears.

So basically `adjust` nodes of subtype `pre` add the content above instead of below the line the `adjust` ends up on after linebreaking.

Comment: Thanks, that makes it very clear!